# Crontab scheduler not able to run safari using selenium

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver, cron, safari

I am trying to open safari browser using selenium, Also using crontab to schedule it.
when I run my code manually through code or terminal it works fine, but when I schedule it using crontab, it failed giving this error. How can I resolve this?

**code to open safari:**

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

    public class SafariDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
            driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com/");
            driver.findElement(By.name("q")).click();
            driver.close();
        }
    }
```

**ERROR:**

> ERROR: safaridriver could not launch because it is not configured
> correctly or you need to authenticate. Re-run safaridriver(1) and
> pass the '--enable' flag to configure and/or authenticate.
> For more information, consult the safaridriver(1) man page.
> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:1709
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
> System info: host: 'GauravKumar-MAC.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:809:261e:c8d9:42a1%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.7', java.version: '1.8.0_382'
> Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
> at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.(SafariDriver.java:81)
> at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.(SafariDriver.java:63)
> at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.(SafariDriver.java:41)
> at org.example.SafariDemo.main(SafariDemo.java:12)
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:1709
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
> at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
> atokhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
> at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
> at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
> ... 7 more
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
> at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
> at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:613)
> at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)

Comment: Probably a permissions problem.  Try running the cron job as a specific user that has access to Safari.